# getting duplicate data in stream builder flutter

Tags: flutter

I hope you guys are happy and healthy

I am facing a problem in flutter
i will be very thankful to you if any of you help me resolving this issue

I am trying to fetch data from api
and show it in alphabetic list with the help of stream builder
but i am getting the same data multiple of time
let me show you the code

here i am trying to fetch data from api and convert it into list

```
Future<List<DisplayClients>> getClientList() async {
String email = widget.email;
final response = await http.get(
  Uri.parse(
      api),
);
if (response.statusCode == 200) {
  final parsed = json.decode(response.body).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();

  var list = parsed
      .map<DisplayClients>(
        (json) => DisplayClients.fromMap(json),
      )
      .toList();
  print('clientList');
  print(list.length);

  for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    clientList.add(AlphabetSearchModel(
        title: list[i].name,
        subtitle: list[i].email,
        phoneNumber: list[i].phoneNumber));
  }
  print(clientList);

  return parsed
      .map<DisplayClients>(
        (json) => DisplayClients.fromMap(json),
      )
      .toList();
} else {
  throw Exception('Failed to load album');
}
}
```

here i am showing i am using data in streamBuilder

```
StreamBuilder<List<DisplayClients>>(
              stream: getClientsStream(),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  // var list = s
                  print('got data');
                  print(snapshot.data!.length);
                  return SizedBox(
                      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.7,
                      child: AlphabetSearchView.modelList(
                        list: clientList,
                        buildItem: (context, index, item) {
                          return Padding(
                              padding:
                                  const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 6),
                              child: Card(
                                  // margin: EdgeInsets.all(12),
                                  elevation: 3,
                                  color: Constants.purpleLight,
                                  shadowColor: Colors.white,
                                  child: Row(children: [
                                    Padding(
                                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                      child: Container(
                                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                            shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                            gradient: LinearGradient(
                                                colors: [
                                                  Constants.red,
                                                  Constants.orange,
                                                ],
                                                begin: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                                                end: Alignment.topRight)),
                                        child: CircleAvatar(
                                            radius: 40,
                                            child: Icon(
                                              Icons.person,
                                              color: Colors.white,
                                              size: 40,
                                            ),
                                            backgroundColor:
                                                Colors.transparent),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    SizedBox(
                                      width: 10,
                                    ),
                                    CustomText(
                                      text: item.title,
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                      size: 18,
                                      weight: FontWeight.w400,
                                    ),
                                    SizedBox(
                                      width: 10,
                                    ),
                                    CircleAvatar(
                                      backgroundColor: Constants.orange,
                                      radius: 4,
                                    ),
                                    SizedBox(
                                      width: 10,
                                    ),
                                    CustomText(
                                      text: item.subtitle,
                                      color: Colors.white70,
                                      size: 14,
                                      weight: FontWeight.w400,
                                    ),
                                    SizedBox(
                                      width: 10,
                                    ),
                                    CircleAvatar(
                                      backgroundColor: Constants.orange,
                                      radius: 4,
                                    ),
                                    SizedBox(
                                      width: 10,
                                    ),
                                    CustomText(
                                      text: item.phoneNumber,
                                      color: Colors.white70,
                                      size: 14,
                                      weight: FontWeight.w400,
                                    ),
                                    Spacer(),
                                    Padding(
                                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12),
                                      child: primaryButton(
                                          verticalPadding: 0,
                                          context: context,
                                          text: 'Deal with ${item.title}',
                                          onTap: () {
                                            Navigator.push(context,
                                                MaterialPageRoute(
                                                    builder: (context) {
                                              return SeperateClient(
                                                  clientName: item.title,
                                                  email: widget.email,
                                                  clientEmail:
                                                      item.subtitle!);
                                            }));
                                          }),
                                    )
                                  ])));
                        },
                      )
                      );
                }
                return Container();
              },
            )
```

i am calling getClientList() method in initSate

here is code for getClientStream()

```
  Stream<List<DisplayClients>> getClientsStream() async* {
while (true) {
  await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 1));
  yield await getClientList();
}
```

}

this code is returning multiple data's
please let me know where i am making mistakes
i will be thankful to you

Thanks :)

Comment: Can you share the code for `getClientsStream`?

Comment: @MyCar   Stream<List<DisplayClients>> getClientsStream() async* {
    while (true) {
      await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 1));
      yield await getClientList();
    }
  }

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
Stream<List<DisplayClients>> getClientsStream() async* {
  await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 1));
  String email = widget.email;
  final response = await http.get(
    Uri.parse(api),
  );
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    final parsed = json.decode(response.body).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();

    var list = parsed
        .map<DisplayClients>(
          (json) => DisplayClients.fromMap(json),
        )
        .toList();
    print('clientList');
    print(list.length);

    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
      clientList.add(AlphabetSearchModel(title: list[i].name, subtitle: list[i].email, phoneNumber: list[i].phoneNumber));
    }
    print(clientList);

    yield* parsed
        .map<DisplayClients>(
          (json) => DisplayClients.fromMap(json),
        )
        .toList();
  } else {
    throw Exception('Failed to load album');
  }
}
```

Comment: nope this is not working
Error: Expected a value of type 'Stream<List<DisplayClients>>', but got one of type 'List<DisplayClients>'

getting this error

Comment: @MAHI which line of code is wrong?

Comment: i am getting this message in debug console @MyCar

Comment: @MAHI can you share the **entire** error message

Comment: i already did... nothing more i am getting